# Как находить лучшие статьи wikipedia или какие инструменты для этого использовать?

Tags: python, windows, api, mediawiki

Учусь программировать на python. Цель стоит такая, хочу вытягивать лучшие фильмы, за определенное время, что сейчас популярное из статьям по годам в Википедии. Посоветуйте, как можно вытянуть. Через API, инструменты, сайты

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог (галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 4):

[wikipedia(library)](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/)

```
pip install wikipedia
```

```
>>> ny = wikipedia.page("New York")
>>> ny.title
# u'New York'
>>> ny.url
# u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York'
>>> ny.content
# u'New York is a state in the Northeastern region of the United States. New York is the 27th-most exten'...
>>> ny.links[0]
# u'1790 United States Census'
```

Вот еще мой старый код на bs4 (install:`pip3 install bs4`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = Soup(main_text)

data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-parser-output'})
print(data.p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно поняла вопрос, то пользуюсь сама https://wikirank.net/

Там можно найти что сейчас в Википедии больше просматриваются пользователями. Можно на разных языках. На данный момент их там не много. Но для своей дипломной использовала 5 языков основных. А темы были как раз с "Автоматической оценки качества статей" и "Data Mining"

[image: так собственно выглядит сам ресурс]

Для себя было интересно поискать лучшие фильмы:
[image: викиранк фильмы рейтинг]

вот так выглядит [русская версия](https://ru.wikirank.net/top/film):
[image: Русская версия wikirank.net]

нашла как-то на хабре [откуда прочитала про wikirank](https://habr.com/ru/post/347376/)